# Sending APNs notification returns Success but no notification appears on phone

Tags: python, apple-push-notifications, python-3.7, http2

I'm trying to send a push notification on an iphone using the pushjack library
(https://github.com/joseph-fox/pushjack).

I'm trying to run the provided example using my company's test phone token and pem file.

The code that I'm trying to run is this:

```py
 
    from pushjack_http2 import APNSClient

    client = APNSClient(certificate='<mypem>.pem',
                        default_error_timeout=10,
                        default_expiration_offset=2592000,
                        default_batch_size=100,
                        default_retries=5)

    token = '<mytoken>'
    alert = 'Hello world.'

    res = client.send([token], alert)

    resp = {'successes': res.successes, 'failures': res.failures, 'tokens_sent': res.tokens, 'errors': res.errors,
            'token_errors': res.token_errors}
    return resp
```

and the response that I'm getting is the following:

```
{'successes': ['<mytoken>'], 'failures': [], 'tokens_sent': ['<mytoken>'], 'errors': [], 'token_errors': {}}
```

When using the same .pem and token via pushtry (https://pushtry.com/) I'm having the notification appear correctly on the phone (I wonder if it has to do with the bundle id which I also provided there, but had no option to provide in the sample code).

This is a rather vague question, but, does anybody have any idea why this would happen?
I've tried both the dev and the production .pem file and both return a success while none has a notification correctly pop up. Do you have any idea on what could be wrong or how I could probe around to find what's wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I didn't realise that apple changed something in their backend on March31 and the library I was trying to use was deprecated.

Solved it using apns2 instead.